# How can one disable screen mirroring permanently in Mac Os Monterey?

Tags: display, monterey, preferences

I know how to disable screen mirroring in Monterey, but, when the laptop goes into power saving mode, it reverts back to mirroring, and I have to change it back again through preferences.
Is there anyway to make the change more permanent?

**NOTE**:

It is a brand new system so I'm quite new to Monterey.
I have a Big Sur OS on another laptop and do not have the same issue. Or at least, the system remembers the display screen settings.

Comment: You might have trouble getting an answer, since what you're asking for is how it works for me/how it's supposed to work. Something is definitely wrong on your end. Hopefully someone else has run into this before and knows the fix.

Comment: @Ezekiel I described it's current behaviour and I'm asking how to persist that behaviour to make it more permanent. Also I don't see how something is wrong on my end since it's actually a brand new system.
I have a Big Sur system where I do not have this issue so I surmise that it is a **Monterey feature regress** unless the route to achieving what I want to achieve has been changed on this new OS.

Comment: I'm not saying you're doing something wrong - I'm saying for everyone else it does stay permanent so we don't know how to help

Comment: What is the second screen involved in this, and how is it connected? What model of Mac laptop? Do you mean "Low Power Mode", when the battery is at 10%?

Comment: Actually there were 2 screens involved. One was connected via HDMI and the other via the USB C interface. It's a '22 M1 pro MBP. 
The issue though, seems to have resolved itself after a day or two. I
t started remembering the display settings.